# touchpad recognized as a mouse on asus x556ua

Tags: touchpad

I have an asus x556ua laptop with ubuntu 16.04.1, and the touchpad works but no gestures work , also in the touchpad/mouse settings there is no touchpad, it is recognized as a normal mouse.

I'm including the output of:

```
xinput

xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3
```

)]

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears this issue has allready been adressed.
There is a bug report about this here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1587913

At the end of the bug report there is a link to the site where the module that solves the problem can be downloaded.
The link to the module download is :

https://github.com/vlasenko/hid-asus-dkms

I have tested it with my asus x556uak laptop with 7th gen processor kaby lake using ubuntu 16.04.1 and it works.
It also fixes the touchpad function button which can now activate and deactive the touchpad.